# Working with a toString and a queue in Java

Tags: java, queue

I've switched everything around within my toString to try and get the result I wanted, but I'm having no luck. I'm trying to get this result:

```
QUEUE TESTING

3

7

7

4

The size of the queue is: 3

The queue contains:

4 9 8
```

But instead, I'm getting this:

```
QUEUE TESTING
3
7
7
4
The size of the queue is: 3
The queue contains:
 9 8
```

And I can't understand why the four isn't being returned with the 9 and 8. Can someone please tell me whats going on. Thanks!

Here's the code I'm working with (attached files left-out):

```
public class Murray_A06Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedQueue<Integer> queue = new LinkedQueue<Integer>();
        System.out.println("QUEUE TESTING");

        queue.enqueue(3);
        queue.enqueue(7);
        queue.enqueue(4);
        System.out.println(queue.first());
        queue.dequeue();        
        queue.enqueue(9);
        queue.enqueue(8);
        System.out.println(queue.first());        
        System.out.println(queue.dequeue());
        System.out.println(queue.first());        

        System.out.println("The size of the queue is: " + queue.size());
        System.out.println("The queue contains:\n" + queue.toString());        
    }


  public static class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T> {
    private int count;
    private LinearNode<T> head, tail; //front, back

    // Constructor      
    public LinkedQueue() {
        count = 0;
        head = tail = null;
    }

    // Adds the specified element to the tail of this queue.   
    public void enqueue(T element) {

        LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T>(element);

        if (isEmpty())
            head = node;
        else
            tail.setNext(node);

        tail = node;
        count++;
    }

    //Removes the element at the head of this queue and returns a
    public T dequeue() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("queue");

        T result = head.getElement();
        head = head.getNext();
        count--;

        if (isEmpty())
            tail = null;

        return result;
    } // End of dequeue

    // first() throws EmptyCollectionException         
    public T first() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        return head.getElement();
    }

    // Beginning of isEmpty()           
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(count == 0){
            return true;
        }   
        else {
            return false;           
        }
    } // End of isEmpty()

    // Beginning of size()          
    public int size() {
        return count;
    }

    // Begin of toString() method           
    public String toString() {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            return " ";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        LinearNode<T> next = head.getNext();

        while(next != null){
            sb.append(" ").append(next.getElement());
            next = next.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();   
    } // End of toString method

  }

}
```

Comment: Is it because you are starting at the node `head.getNext();` instead of starting with the node `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your toString method like this:

```
public String toString() {

    if (isEmpty()) {
        return " ";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    LinearNode<T> next = head;

    while(next != null){
        sb.append(" ").append(next.getElement());
        next = next.getNext();
    }

    return sb.toString();

} // End of toString method
```

toString was never printing the HEAD value since you assigned head.getNext to next before your while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting with the second element.  In `toString()`, you initialize `next` with `head.getNext()`, where `head` is the first and `head.next()` is the second element.  This causes the output to skip the first element, and this would cause a `NullPointerException` if there were exactly one element in the queue.

Initialize `next` to `head` instead.